# Spring integration:imap - error: Target object of type [class myEmailReciever] has no eligible methods for handling Messages

Tags: spring, email, exception, imap, spring-integration

I'm trying to use spring integration email mechanism.
I used this link for reference:
http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/04/read-emails-from-imap-with-spring.html

unfortunately i get an error message on server start-up:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object of type [class src.com.project.myEmailReciever] has no eligible methods for handling Messages.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:294)
at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:348)
at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:165)
at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:103)
at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:107)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:48)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.<init>(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:42)
at org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean.createMethodInvokingHandler(ServiceActivatorFactoryBean.java:48)
at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandler(AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:72)
at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:89)
at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:68)
at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:31)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
... 30 more
```

apparently the function in my  receiving  class :

```
public void receive(MimeMessage mimeMessage) {

//doSomthing
   }
```

is not eligible for handling emails.. anyone know how do i solve this?

*edit* here are my classes\ xml's:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MessageFactory {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageFactory.class);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


public boolean receive(MimeMessage mimeMessage) {

    System.out.println("try");
    return true;
   }
}
```

xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
</util:properties>

<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                                  store-uri="imaps://username:password@imap.googlemail.com:993/INBOX"                                    
                                  channel="recieveEmailChannel"                                         
                                  should-delete-messages="false"
                                  should-mark-messages-as-read="true"                                     
                                  auto-startup="true"

                                  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">

    <int:poller fixed-delay="5" time-unit="SECONDS" />
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel">       
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel" ref="messageFactory" method="receive"/>

<bean id="messageFactory" class="src.com.project.service.factories.MessageFactory">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error generally is a configuration problem.

Conditions that might cause it include...

- Misspelled `method` attribute in the `<service-activator/>` configuration
- The method's not public
- `requires-reply="true"` and the method returns void (like yours)

Comment: Not working, I added my classes\xml into my post please see if you can spot any errors , thanks

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. I just copied/pasted your code/config into one of my apps and it works just fine. Your original log has a different class (src.com.project.myEmailReciever). Are you still getting the same exception? Given that you are now returning a `boolean`, you need an `output-channel` on the service activator. You can set it to `nullChannel` to discard, or change the signature to return `void`. If you still can't work it out, maybe you can post a full DEBUG log (for `org.springframework`) someplace?

Comment: I got similar error and fixed in my config xml. Reason: I used to have somemethod in service activator, and part of refactoring it was moved to a differen class but the config still has the tag => <int:service-activator .. method="somemethod".../> . Removed the tag and it works! So agree with @GaryRussell

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring Integration 2.2.4 and I was having this problem. I saw another post that said that @Header does not work in some versions of Spring Integration. Unfortunately, I can't upgrade right now. So, the choices were to try using @Headers or use an expression. I used an expression and it is working for me...

```
<service-activator expression="@myService.serviceMethod(headers.customerKey, payload)"/>
```